# Issue when saving to Date/Time field in Deluge function

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I am new to Deluge and I'm trying to write a function that is triggered by a button that makes an api request and stores details from the response into a record of a custom module.

Everything seems to be working as expected with one exception, I am trying to save the timestamp of when the request was made and store that in a date/time field on the custom module.

I have tried to use the `zoho.currenttime` function, which seemed to give me what I needed: ("14-Mar-2023 13:01:57"). This looks like a date/time field to me.

Here is a more complete snippet for reference:

```
Request_Log.put("Send_Date_Time", zoho.currenttime);
Request_Record = zoho.crm.createRecord("Request_Log",Request_Log);
info Request_Record;
```

Which results in this error:

```
"{"code":"INVALID_DATA","details":{"expected_data_type":"datetime","api_name":"Send_Date_Time"},"message":"invalid data","status":"error"}"
```

And thus the "Request_Log" record is not created.

What am I missing here? How can I format the date time value from "zoho.currenttime" to allow my new record to be created?

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

"Send_Date_Time" may expect ISO8601 datetime format.  This is the case with some of Zoho's datatime fields.

ISO8601 format is: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss±HH:mm`

Example: 2023-03-19T09:10:30+06:00

Notes:

- The 'T' is exactly that, a 'T' character.
- The time after the +/- is the local offset from UTC time.

Here is the code that should get the zoho.currenttime into ISO8601 format:

```
...    
iso8601_date = zoho.currenttime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
info iso8601_date;
Request_Log.put("Send_Date_Time", iso8601_date);
...
```